# Adding a property to a silverlight 4 control to add functionality

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, dependency-properties, attached-properties

I am curious how I can add a property to add functionality to a control. Currently I am just extending controls, but I was curious if it is possible to add a property to add functionality to a control. Like for example the ToolTipService. You can add that to controls. Would it be possible for me to add a property to add a contextmenu without having to extend a textbox lets say? I know about behaviors, but is it possible to do that as a property? Let's say I add a property IsContextMenuBehaviorAdded="True" and that will just attach a behavior, or just add functionality. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to add a context menu to a control then you can do that with the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/43528) which contains a `ContextMenuService`.

Comment: I have an extended contextmenu control. is it possible to use that with the contextmenuservice?

Comment: @pqsk:  I your controls extends the the Toolkit `ContextMenu` then yes.

Comment: Awesome. Just one more question. Say on my view I have a few textboxes that I want this contextmenu to be in. I see that the ContextMenuService has some properties. Is it possible to make that a usercontrol resource so I wouldn't have to write all the properties for each textbox?